# Collaborate with R using a unique identifier for computer

Tags: r

I am collaborating on an R project with a group. Some of us are using Linux, some Macs, and some Windows.

Getting a script running on multiple computers can be a challenge since people may have stored their local data in a variety of places.

Therefore, it would be handy if R had a command that could uniquely identify the computer, say by returning the MAC address, or what not.

The script could then begin with a section which sets up each collaborator's environment without requiring their intervention:

```
computer_id<-GetUniqueIDofComputerCommand()
if(computer_id=="23:AB:42"){ #Bob's Computer

} else if(computer_id="43:99:FF") { #Frank's computer

}
```

Does such a command exist, or is there some other workaround?

Comment: I think the "workaround" is to agree upon some distributed version control system that your team will use, like github.

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem that there are many ways to initialize an R script and some of them require collaborator-specific work.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "many ways to initialize an R script", and collaborator specific work can all be put in version control so it is available to everyone. That's the whole point of working in a version control system. I guess I just don't understand what your problem is at all, sorry.

Comment: If you're willing to each set/use a different `USERNAME` on the relevant computers, scripts could identify which computer they're on by using something like: `Sys.getenv("USERNAME")`

Comment: It's the path to the local data/configuration that should be provided as an argument to the script or read in from the environment. Don't put alternate behavior per username within the script itself.